# SSAS OLAP multidimensional data disappears on deployment

Tags: ssas, olap-cube

Been looking around for quite a bit to see if someone could provide me with any directions and/or tests to fix this issue. Unsuccessful so far.

I'm working on a clients multidimensional cube (they have several in the same warehouse), and have created my own development copy from that exact cube so i don't break anything in production, while developing.

The issue is that whenever i edit my cube, and then deploy it removes the data from the cube, and in some programs the cube disappears all together. The cube itself is still visible in SSMS but contains no data.

I then have to do a full process of the entire database to get data back, which is rather annoying given it takes around 30-40 minutes where i then cannot work on it and its a minor change i've made (such as changing the Order property of a dimension from Name to Key or creating a Measure group)

**Some settings/extra info:**

- When i deploy i have specified the cube to Do Not Process due to some prior processing issues when processing from BIDS
- I have a delta process to keep data up to date, that runs continuously  and doesn't fail. It moves no data to the failed cube however, but other cubes present works just fine.
- In script view the first mdx statement under calculations is a calculate statement [as some source suggested](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2011/10/20/why-has-all-the-data-in-my-cube-disappeared/) could be an issue if not.
- It is deployed from VS 2008 (clients version)
- Deploying to Localhost
- The view upon which some dimensions are built, contain Union statements, but only contain a few records

**Scenarios where it fails:**

- Refresh data source view
- Create new dimension
- Change dimension properties
- Create measure groups
- Updating dimensions
- Properly more that i either haven't tested or can't remember

Does anyone have any idea of the issue and how to fix it? I really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is expected behaviour. SSAS creates aggregations during processing; in case the structure of the cube/dimension is changed then the existing aggregations become invalid and the entire cube goes into the "Unprocessed" state. As you have found out yourself you need to do the full process then to be able to browse the cube.

Here's a blog post with the list of actions and their effect on the state of the cube: http://bimic.blogspot.com/2011/08/ssas-which-change-makes-cubedimension.html

I suggest you create a small data set for the development purposes and test the cube on that data before moving to production. You can also limit the data loaded to the cube by switching to the query (instead of the table) in the partition designer; in the query you can then use WHERE condition to limit the records loaded to the cube and make the processing go faster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) the site did provide me with info. Shame that it is expected behavior. 

I haven't had the issue lately, which i dont really know why since i did not make any significant changes outside of retyping the calculate statement mvoing it from capital letters to regular (mistakenly deleted it).